# Are the tty parameters stored somewhere when using screen?

Tags: usb, serial, stty

Here is the story:

From a fresh install of ubuntu I use a serial to usb device. `screen /dev/ttyUSB0` everything goes fine and I can interact with the device perfectly.

Then I unplug this device, plug another one (a 3g modem). Again `screen /dev/ttyUSB0` and everything is fine.

But then, I plug again the first device and do the `screen /dev/ttyUSB0` and everything got scrambled!

I am supposing that for whatever reason the tty parameters changed. Is there a possibility that `screen` store it somewhere ?
How can I get back to the initial settings ?

So far I have tried:

- rebooting
- stty sane

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

Two screen instance were actually reading /dev/ttyUSB0

Removing them all solved the issue.